# What's the song in Naruto (part 1) episode 107 at 6:51?

Tags: naruto, music

It's a happy sorta flute/guitar song, I always hear it but I just cant seem to find it. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *Daylight of Konoha* By Toshiro Masuda.

The song is part of Naruto's second OST [Naruto - Original soundtrack II](https://www.discogs.com/Toshiro-Masuda-Naruto-Original-Soundtrack-II/release/1914486) published by Miya Records.

The CD is available on [playasia](https://www.play-asia.com/naruto-original-soundtrack-ii/13/707q0) and [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002QI8KE2)